# How to Wait till a DHCP server assign's IP to a first time boot VM with a Sysprepped vhd attached to it using PowerShell in Hyper-V version 3.0

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, powershell-3.0

I'm   going through a scenario where i boot a Newly built VM with a sysprepped vhd attached, once the setup process completes with installing devices etc and the OS gets loaded i wanted to wait till this entire process finishes and the VM is assigned an IP address via DHCP.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-VM -Name dv.VMWIN2K8R2-3.Hng
PS C:\Users\Administrator> while ((Get-VM -Name dv.VMWIN2K8R2-3.Hng | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters).ipaddress[0] -match $null)

 {

 Start-Sleep 3

 Write-Host "Waiting to Acquire IP Address" -ForegroundColor green

 }

$ipaddress=(Get-VM -Name dv.VMWIN2K8R2-2.Hng | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters).ipaddresses[0]

Write-Host "VM has acquired an IPAddress of $ipaddress"
```

I Tried the above snippet but the while loop never run's, i have noticed that while VM is shutdown the ip address parameter is blank so i thought to match it till it shows Null and when i boot up the VM and once the server gets an IP address by DHCP it should exit the while loop and print the IP address on console.

Comment: Ok.  Have you tried using debugging in the ISE?  Store the results of the Get-VM command in a variable, add a breakpoint, and check it out before your while loop.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys i was able to solve the issue, i used the Get-VMNetworkAdapter Cmdlet and it solved the issue

```
while (((Get-VMNetworkAdapter $vmname | select -ExpandProperty ipaddresses) -eq $null -or ((Get-VMNetworkAdapter $vmname | select -ExpandProperty ipaddresses) -match "169.")))

{ 

Write-Progress -Activity "Waiting for VM to Aquire an IPAddress" 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IP is probably not null, so it's doing exactly what it should.  The IP is probably 169.254.x.x, or at least that's what happens to me before I pick up DHCP.  How about choosing the first octet of the address it should have after it picks up an address and using that?

EDIT: Maybe it's not 169 as I thought, after re-reading your post.  My advice still applies.  Try using something like this:  `While (!($ip -like "10.*")`

Comment: I Tried it, the Get-VM needs to check consistently till the server gets IP address while(!(Get-VM -Name dv.VMWIN2K8R2-3.Hng | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters).ipaddress[0] -like "10.*"), but it also did not work, the while loop skipped immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no network stack there are no addresses and I think you'll find the array is not there. Chris is on the right track. I think you'll need to not do what you're doing but first test to see if ipaddress is a property, is an array, and has at least 1 item in it before checking the value of that item.